# How do I unhide the Channels region in Graph Editor?

Tags: interface, graph-editor

I know this may sound stupid but I got a bit angry before and pressed a key by accident that hid the Channels region. I now (hopefully) know what to do, and it involves the Channels region. I don't know why I got so mad, I have a bad temper.

Comment: Not sure about the hotkey, but there should be a very small semi.transparent plus sign along the window border that allows expanding it back up.

Comment: It's fine, I just did a bit more work and it came back. Strange, I know but it just did.